# How to write a jasmine test for the following code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, testing, jasmine

```
var express = require('express');
var items = require('json-fs-store')('src/unit');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/things', function(req, res, next) {
    items.list(function(err, things) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('factories', {companyList: things}); // Render factories.ejs
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have a code something like this. When get request is sent to the server, and array of json files get sent back. I have a code something like this. When get request is sent to the server, and array of json files get sent back. THANK YOU ALL!

```
'use strict';

var request = require('supertest');

describe('Things', function () {
    var app;
    beforeEach(function () {
        app = require('../app.js');
    });
    afterEach(function () {
        app.close();
    });


    it('gets all things', function (done) {
        request(app)
            .get('/things')
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if (err) return done.fail(res);
                expect(res.body.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
                done(res);
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: You could the Sinon library to mock your server (fake server)
http://sinonjs.org/

This way you can control it's answer and you are able write a reliable test.

EDIT:
Anyway, What is your question at all? You've got a test already? Or is it not working?